# Using regex to find deeply nested objects in Javascript source code

Tags: regex, refactoring

I am currently refactoring my codebase to replace code like this:

```
one && one.two && one.two.three
```

with the equivalent using [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining):

```
one?.two?.three
```

but I'm having trouble coming up with a regular expression that matches instances of the former.

---

So far I've come up with [this](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=103925):

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]* && )+
```

which is OK but has a lot of false-positives (matching things like `a && a.c && a.d.e && a.f.g.h`)

---

The regex should match expressions of the form (any length):

- `one && one.two && one.two.three...`
- `one.two && one.two.three && one.two.three.four...`

But not match:

- `one && two...`
- `one && two.three...`

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe something along [`(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\s*&&\s*(\1\.\w+)\s*&&\s*\2\.\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/jsr91Y/1/) which will match condition chains with 3 elements. This will consequently also find larger chains but only match the first 3 elements. If you plan to replace them by hand, that should work anyways.

Comment: @SebastianProske excellent! If you convert to answer I'll gladly accept

Comment: How about [`(\b(\w[\w.]*)(?=( +&& +)\2|$)( +&& +)?){2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/mToPau/1)?

Comment: @revo that also works great :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you can make use of backreferences here and use

```
(\b\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\s*&&\s*(\1\.\w+)\s*&&\s*\2\.\w+
```

to match sequences of 3 elements as shown in your samples, where the first element is a sequence of dot separated words, the second is the first element + dot + another word and the third is the second element + dot + another word.

This will only match the first 3 elements if you have chains of 4 or more, but if you plan to do the replacements by hand, this shouldn't be a blocker.

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/jsr91Y/2/)